# Org mode internal link dynamic naming

Tags: emacs, hyperlink, org-mode

Is there a way to rename links automatically based on the original headline?

Example:

```
* Headline 1
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: some_id
:END:

* Headline 2

 - Headline 1 // this is a link using an id

* Headline 3

 - Headline 1 // this is a link using an id
```

When creating a new internal link, org allows you to specify the text for that link. Is there a way to dynamically change that linking text based on the headline? If I change `Headline 1` to `Headline 4`, I want the text of the links to also change to `Headline 4` automatically.

Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible - but it could be intolerably slow. There is a hook `post-self-insert-hook` that is run after *every character insertion*. So you could write  a function that checks every link's ID and changes the link description appropriately. But you'd only want to modify the hook for Org mode files (which is not difficult) and make the function as fast as possilble, *because it will be run after every character insertion*. This hook is used e.g. to blink the matching opening paren when you type a closing paren - see the function `blink-paren-post-self-insert-function` in `simple.el`.

Comment: (i'm still pretty new to org mode so please excuse any wrong assumptions)

I'm also okay with a scenario where the update does not happen reactively on every character entry, but is triggered with a new key binding. Eg. org-update-link-descriptions-in-buffer, and then we run through the entire buffer and do the update.

This would mean that link descriptions could be out of date for some time, until the function is triggered again. 

I'm more interested in how "So you could write a function that checks every link's ID and changes the link description appropriately." could be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little slow, but this worked:

```
(defun us/description-of-target-link (target-id)
  (car (org-map-entries '(org-entry-get nil "ITEM") (concat "ID=\"" target-id "\"")))
  )

(defun us/update-internal-link-descriptions ()
  (interactive)
  (setq offset 0)
  ;;; map over all elements in the buffer
  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
    (lambda (link)
      ;;; filter to internal links with id
      (when (string= (org-element-property :type link) "id")
        (setq content-start-point-raw (org-element-property :contents-begin link))
        (setq content-end-point-raw (org-element-property :contents-end link))
        (setq len-thing-to-remove (- content-end-point-raw content-start-point-raw))
        (setq new-description (us/description-of-target-link (org-element-property :path link)))
        (setq len-thing-to-add (length new-description))
        (setq offset-delta (- len-thing-to-add len-thing-to-remove))
        (setq content-remove-point-start-with-offset (+ content-start-point-raw offset))
        (setq content-remove-point-end-with-offset (+ content-end-point-raw offset))
        (goto-char content-remove-point-start-with-offset)
        (delete-region content-remove-point-start-with-offset content-remove-point-end-with-offset)
        (insert new-description)
        (setq offset (+ offset offset-delta ))
        )
      )
    )
  )
```